# module.export.variable is always an empty object if its reinitialized

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am confused a bit about the module.exports functionality in the below examples. In case 1, the a.arrayVar in b.js correctly gives all the elements that get added to the array in a.js even during the run time, but the same does not happen in case 2. The only difference in both the cases is the arrayVar is reinitialized in the function in case 2.I have a use case where the array must be reinitialized everytime it is updated dynamically and I am finding it difficult to implement this case. Any help in me understanding the concept in greatly appreciated.

case 1 :

```
// a.js
var arrayVar= [];
module.exports.arrayVar= arrayVar;

function test(element){
arrayVar.push(element);
}


// b.js
var a= require('./a.js');
console.log(a.arrayVar);
```

output: [ 'kafka-topic-1', 'kafka-topic1' ]

case 2 :

```
// a.js
var arrayVar= [];
module.exports.arrayVar= arrayVar;

function test(element){
 arrayVar= [];
 arrayVar.push(element);
}

// b.js
var a= require('./a.js');
console.log(a.arrayVar);
```

output: []

Comment: `module.exports.arrayVar= arrayVar;` means "assign a copy of the *current value* of `arrayVar` to `module.exports.arrayVar`". You are later assigning a *new* value to `arrayVar`. That doesn't magically change/update the value of `module.exports.arrayVar`. JavaScript is *pass-by-value* which means that at assignment/passing, the value of the variable is *copied* (note that the value can be a reference to an object). In other words, `module.exports.arrayVar` doesn't have a *reference to the variable* `arrayVar` but a *copy of `arrayVar`'s value* at that time.

Comment: Why does the array have to be reinitialized every time? That doesn't seem to make much sense to me...

Comment: Thanka lot  for the response.Its been only a week since I started to learn javascript and its really confusing to me. In case 1, the function is called many times in the run time and the new elements keep getting added to the array , and the reference in the b.js always gets the latest value of the arrayVar. Could you please explain how is this happening if the current value of arrayVar is assigned to module.exports.arrayVar.

Comment: In case one you are not changing the value of `arrayVar`, you are only adding more elements to the array it references (i.e. you are adding values to the existing array, you are not creating a new array). Both `arrayVar` and `module.exports.arrayVar` reference *one and the same array*.

Comment: The requirement is that during the application startup, the array loads all the availables from redis, and there is a redis subsccriber which listens on changes to a particular hashkey in redis and the members of the hashkey can be deleted/added/modified. So I have to create a new array with the new contents everytime a redis update happens

Comment: ok.. Thanks a lot, I think in understand it better now. Since the variable is the same, I thought re-initializing it doesn't make difference. But it doesnt seem to work that way,and is creating a new instance.

Comment: @KBSri In that case, don't only reinitialise the local variable but also the exported property.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a you are always referring to the same instance of the array. In the case of b, re-assigning arrayVar creates a new instance of the array object, which is different from the one passed in the export.

If you need to re initialize the array, use the splice method, or set the length to 0, but make sure you are using the same object

Comment: Thanks a lot. I could make it work using arrayVar.length=0.Is there a way to  achieve this in case of javascript object.

Comment: Simply delete the attribute of the object (use the delete operator) like ‘delete myObject.myAttr‘

Comment: Thank you so much!! You have answered all my queries, but I am sorry that I dont have enough reputation to accept the answer.. Thank You!